# SSRS Subscriptions - Windows Share Error: Failure writing file: XXX : The network name cannot be found

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

When trying to create a subscription of a report, that delivers the report via Windows File Share, I am receiving this error:

[image]

This is a valid location, as demonstrated:

[image]

The report subscription values read:

[image]

The credentials for this report is `vendoradmin`. This user has full access to the directory:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default setup for the D$ shares is for machine administrators. If the user account that SSRS is running under is not an administrator it will not be able to write to the share.

By using \localhost\D$ it is accessing the local D drive. It should work by just specifying D:\PrimeCare\import\sprinkle. Other users can then access the location with \{servername}\d$\PrimeCare\import\sprinkle